# Wrong CRLF in UTF-16 stream?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, unicode, newline

Here is a problem I could not solve despite all my efforts. So I am totally stuck, please help!

For regular, “ASCII” mode the following simplified file and stream outputs

```
FILE *fa = fopen("utfOutFA.txt", "w");
fprintf(fa, "Line1\nLine2");
fclose(fa);
ofstream sa("utfOutSA.txt");
sa << "Line1\nLine2";
sa.close();
```

result, naturally, in exactly the same text files (hex dump):

```
00000000h: 4C 69 6E 65 31 0D 0A 4C 69 6E 65 32             ; Line1..Line2
```

where the new line `\n` is expanded to CRLF: `0D 0A` – typical for Windows.

Now, we do the same for Unicode output, namely UTF-16 LE which is a sort of “default”. File output

```
FILE *fu = fopen("utfOutFU.txt", "w, ccs=UNICODE");
fwprintf(fu, L"Line1\nLine2");
fclose(fu);
```

results in this contents:

```
00000000h: FF FE 4C 00 69 00 6E 00 65 00 31 00 0D 00 0A 00 ; ÿþL.i.n.e.1.....
00000010h: 4C 00 69 00 6E 00 65 00 32 00                   ; L.i.n.e.2.
```

which looks perfectly correct considering BOM and endianness, including CRLF: `0D 00 0A 00`. However, the similar stream output

```
wofstream su("utfOutSU.txt");
su.imbue(locale(locale::empty(), new codecvt_utf16<wchar_t, 0x10ffffUL, 
                            codecvt_mode(generate_header + little_endian)>));
su << L"Line1\nLine2";
su.close();
```

results in one byte less and overall incorrect text file:

```
00000000h: FF FE 4C 00 69 00 6E 00 65 00 31 00 0D 0A 00 4C ; ÿþL.i.n.e.1....L
00000010h: 00 69 00 6E 00 65 00 32 00                      ; .i.n.e.2.
```

The reason is wrong expansion of CRLF: `0D 0A 00`. Is this a bug? Or have I done something wrong?

I use Microsoft Visual Studio compiler (14.0 and other). I tried using stream `endl` instead of `\n` – same result! I tried to put `su.imbue()` first and then `su.open()` – all the same! I also checked the UTF-8 output (`ccs=UTF-8` for file and `codecvt_utf8` for stream) – no problem as CRLF stays the same as in ASCII mode: `0D 0A`

I appreciate any ideas and comments on the issue.

Comment: This is most probably a bug, because UTF-16 cannot have an odd number of bytes.

Comment: remove `imbue`. Also you can try `.write()`

Comment: `imbue` is needed to setup encoding. Without it there is no point of discussion.

Comment: I am having the same problem writing Japanese text files with notepad (version 21H2) and notepad++ (v8.3.3). They are both terminating lines with 0d 0a 00. Maybe this bug has become a new "standard".

Answer (score 3):

When you are `imbue()`'ing a new locale into the `std::wofstream`, you are wiping out its original locale.  Don't use `locale::empty()`, use `su.getloc()` instead, so the new locale copies the old locale before modifying it.

Also, on a side note, the last template parameter of `codecvt_utf16` is a bitmask, so `codecvt_mode(generate_header + little_endian)` really should be `std::generate_header | std::little_endian` instead.

```
su.imbue(std::locale(su.getloc(), new codecvt_utf16<wchar_t, 0x10ffffUL, 
                            std::generate_header | std::little_endian>));
```

Comment: There is no difference between `+` and `|` when the bits in each operand don't overlap, but your point is a good one.

Comment: Thanks for showing me `getloc()` - I'm pretty novice in this area.

Comment: As for codecvt mode, I had `|` in the early stage; then changed it to `+` while struggling with compiler `error C2440: 'specialization' : cannot convert from 'int' to 'std::codecvt_mode'`; then finally had to add an expliticit cast, but neglected to change it back to `|`. Thanks anyway.

Comment: Anyway, unfortunately all these do not affect the original CLRF issue at all :(

Answer (score 0):

I've discovered that this problem comes from the fact that you are writing the file in text mode. What you want to do is open your output file in binary and the issue will be solved, like so:

```
wofstream su("utfOutSU.txt", ofstream::out | ofstream::binary);
su.imbue(locale(su.getloc(), new codecvt_utf16<wchar_t, 0x10ffffUL, 
                            codecvt_mode(generate_header + little_endian)>));
su << L"Line1\r\nLine2";
su.close();
```

Something "clever" is probably done behinde the scenes when writing text.

Comment: Binary mode certainly works! But in this case there is no automatic CRLF processing - I must do all manually.